# T&P drain line needs to be outside of the house?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I called the gas company to turn on gas. But the engineer left a note saying that "T&P drain line needs to be run outside of house". I called my plumber but he didn't know such a thing. Can someone help?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to the relief valve drain pipe on your water heater?

Comment: "T&P" = "temperature and pressure"?

Comment: Where does it currently drain?

Comment: If this is a new install unless in a garage they need to be outside. I think this is silly though because most just dump through the floor. How do you know you have a problem or a leak in the relief valve.

Comment: What state/country do you live in? Need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I just double checked my state rules ,,, all over pressure / temp valves must vent/ exhaust outside a habitual space. If inside the house it needs to go out of the living space. in the garage I think it said 6" above the slab maybe 6' but it was allowed to vent on the slab.